# Best place for this question

Tags: discussion, site-rec

My question is:

Is it good practice to add version numbers to functions/class? That is when you update a core function/class you update an internal version number for that function/class. I recently thought about doing this internally to some of my core functions and classes.

Is there a SE site for a question like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it hasn't been asked here before but it's a software design topic so feel free to ask it here.

Comment: I would add that the question should be backed up with some research and acknowledgement of the obvious difficulties like updating a hundred assemblies can be a pain.